# Unable to publish Tableau Dashboard to public

Tags: tableau-api

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pE6Jw.png)

Iam trying to share the dashboard created to my public profile and it throws this error :
Screenshot attached.

Comment: does the answer help with your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You just have to click on your Data menu, identify your datasource and then selecting Extract Data.

Doing so, you'll create an extract which will be "send" to Tableau Public when you publish your workbook.